# Why does requireing the text plugin work one way but not another?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When I try to load the `text` plugin of requirejs using the full path, `"Scripts/text"`, it throws a script error.

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 30,
    paths: {
    }
});

var libs = ["Scripts/knockout-3.3.0", "Scripts/Application", "Scripts/text"];

define(libs, function (ko, application) {
    //implementation
}
```

[image]

But when the text plugin path is defined in `path` in the config, it works.

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 30,
    paths: {
        text: "Scripts/text"
    }
});

var libs = ["Scripts/knockout-3.3.0", "Scripts/Application", "text"];

define(libs, function (ko, application) {
    //implementation
}
```

Why is that? Shouldn't it be completely irrelevant where the path to the text plugin is defined?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your first snippet which you say is failing refers to the `text` plugin as `Scripts/text`. However, your error message mentions a failure to load the module named `text`. When I try replicating the error you say you are having, the error message reported by RequireJS is not that it cannot load `text` but that it cannot load `Scripts/text`. In other words, if you were having the error you think you are having, the error message would be different from the one you show in the question. I deduce that the problem is not where you think it is.

Most likely, **another module** in your code base refers to the `text` plugin as `text`. In your first configuration, you do not have a `paths` definition for it, so the loading fails. In your second configuration, you do have a `paths` definition, so the loading works.